# Bootstrap and image width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and my page should have 2 rows. The first row should have two logos (219px width and 61px width) and a menu div. The second row should have big logo (749px width) and a menu div. So I wrote the following code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="images/LEFT_LOGO.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="images/RIGHT_LOGO.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-right">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">Right menu 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="images/BIG_LOGO.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">Right menu 2</div>
        </div>
```

When I run my HTML page then RIGHT_LOGO.jpg and BIG_LOGO.jpg don't align correctly. How can I set up it so that LEFT_LOGO.jpg aligns to left side of BIG_LOGO.jpg and RIGHT_LOGO.jpg aligns to right side of BIG_LOGO.jpg? It seems like col-md-10 class should be equal to width of BIG_LOGO.jpg. But I am not sure how to approach this issue.

Comment: Here's a starting point. Can you demonstrate the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7qL3fkwz

Comment: Basically Nick Tiberi told the solution. But this solution messes up image quality as this image is low resolution.

Comment: Give us what we need to help you. I don't even know in what way the images are misaligned.

Comment: When I execute my code the length of area in a row where LEFT_LOGO.jpg and RIGHT_LOGO.jpg reside is too wide. It shouldn't be longer than the width of BIG_LOGO.jpg.

Comment: If you look at jsfiddle rendered result  jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7qL3fkwz  you see that right side of right upper logo dont line up with right side of bottom logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the width of `BIG_LOGO.jpg` to `100%`. That should make it fill the width of `col-md-10` and the left and right images should line up on the respective sides.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <img src="images/BIG_LOGO.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: This way they really line up correctly but it streched out <code>BIG_LOGO.jpg</code>. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: You could just put a max-width on your container, e.g. `<div class="container" style="max-width: 1000px;"></div>`. That should minimize stretching of the image.

Comment: Nick, you are totally right. It works, I must change container max-width. Thank you. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, adding the `pull-right` class to the lower image solves the problem.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="images/BIG_LOGO.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-right">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7qL3fkwz/6)

And yes, your big image needs to be large enough.

Comment: Unfortunately my big image is not large enough.